# Bloquear SnackBar repetida veces

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnacbarView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnacbarView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void _showSnackBar() {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('SnackBar de ejemplo', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1300),
          )
      );
    }

    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('ShowSnackBar'),
      onPress: () { _showSnackBar() }
    );
  }
}
```

Quiero que cuando pulse dos veces seguidas el botón no solicite dos veces mostrarlo, porque esto lo que esperara a que el primero se cierre y luego abrir el segundo. Es decir, si yo pulso dos veces seguidas el botón si el snackbar esta mostrado esa petición la obviara

Comment: Si editas el mensaje y lo haces comprensible, casi que mejor. Además, ¿qué has intentado? Recuerda que SO no es un sitio para que te hagan las tareas de clases o tu trabajo, sino para ayudar a gente que previamente ha intentado resolver las cosas por su cuenta.